# Wifi drop out on macbook pro retina late 2013 with El Capitan

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

Constant wi fi drop out only on my Macbook pro retina (late 2013) with el capitan installed. My imac is not affected, nor any other appliance using the wifi in our house. Can anyone help? Will the solution posted previously about similar problem with Yosemite work for El Capitan? Thanks in adavance

Answer (score -1):

Change your security from wpa2 to wpa. Helped me solving this problems.